# deployer: 'composer install' - command not found

Tags: php, deployment, composer-php, php-deployer

I am using deployer to package a symfony application on the server. During the deploy I also need to run composer install to run important commands like bin/console. Only then the deployment can be completed. Unfortunately the deployment fails and interrupts at 'composer install' with the error message:

```
[Deployer\Exception\RuntimeException (127)]
The command "cd /usr/home/xxx/public_html/sw6-staging/releases/1.1 && composer install" failed.
Exit Code: 127 (Command not found)
================
bash: line 1: composer: command not found
```

This is the task in the deploy.php looks:

```
task('sw:deploy', function(){
run('cd {{release_path}} && composer install');
});

task('deploy', [
'deploy:prepare',
'deploy:lock',
'deploy:release',
'deploy:update_code',
'sw:deploy',
])->desc('Deploy your project');
```

But if I run the command 'composer install' directly on the server via CLI it runs through. What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Deployer version 6.8.
PHP version 7.2

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. It seems that [deployer](https://deployer.org) connects to the server with a non-login, non-interactive shell, that doesn't load the shell startup files like `~/.bash_profile` -> `~/.bash_login` -> `~/.profile`.

In my case the `.bashrc` had the following entry:

```js
PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$HOME/.linuxbrew/sbin:$PATH"
```

but wether `node`, nor `npm` or `composer` where reachable, so obviously this file wasn't used. Also there were no `~/.bash_profile` so I created one and added the path there too:

```
echo "PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$HOME/.linuxbrew/sbin:$PATH" > ~/.bash_profile
```

Then I used the `source` command to load `~/.bash_profile` before the `composer install` were called:

```php
task('sw:build', static function () {
    run('source /usr/home/username/.bash_profile && cd {{release_path}} && composer install');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Within 6.8, you can [use `shellCommand` option](https://github.com/deployphp/deployer/pull/1536) to have a "login shell" (and load the shell startup files) :

```php
host('example.com')
    ->shellCommand('bash -ls')
```

```yaml
example.com:
  shellCommand : bash -ls
```